# Is there a PostgreSQL view for memory usage?

Tags: postgresql, memory, sql-view, usage-statistics

I know that there is `pg_top`. Due to some limiatations, I cannot install `pg_top`. Additionally, I know that I can monitor memory usage through Linux/UNIX tools.

However, I want to know if there is any Postgres view that will let me view the memory usage. Preferably, one that breaks down the usage to memory taken by PostgreSQL's `MemoryContext`, which appears to grow indefinitly, and the other showing memory used by other components such as the bufferpool etc.

Comment: There is no such view in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Any views that show any type of memory usage?